# Motion Blur not working for newly imported SVGs

Tags: motion-blur

I returned to an older project because client needed a revision. Originally I had 2 imported SVG files of some typogaphy and those blur fine, but when I returned a month later and needed to update the copy the new SVG won't blur in the render but the original SVGs still do (w same animation). Help??

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out, I forgot to "convert to mesh" hopefully this helps someone!

Comment: Motion blur should work with curves as well. Perhaps you can investigate further and check what the actual root cause was?